# AWS Quicksight: How do you update the data in a file upload data source

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

I need to point existing dashboards to a new version of the data. Can I do this without recreating the entire dashboard against a new file upload?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can.

If you look in the top left of an Analysis (which is what a dashboard is created from through publishing) you'll see an option for "Data Set". Click that and you can use the 2 squares + right-angled arrow icon

[image]

to switch it out with another data set.

Note that the data set should closely match the previous data set or you'll have to go through manually and fix all the fields that don't match (it will point out which these are)

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't seem like it. Your best alternative is probably uploading that file to S3 and have QuickSight use that instead